# How to output the columns with the maximum value

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data that I want to find out which column has the maximum value and output that column name. One issue is that if there is no maximum value (e.g, all numeric numbers equal) return `all_equal` comment or if two column has equal max value compared to the third one output those two column name.

Here is the sample data

```
test <- data.frame(A=c(5,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,3,NA,NA),B=c(NA,2,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,1,NA),C=c(NA,NA,1,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,3),gr=gl(3,3))

   A  B  C gr
1  5 NA NA  1
2 NA  2 NA  1
3 NA NA  1  1
4  1 NA NA  2
5 NA  1 NA  2
6 NA NA  1  2
7  3 NA NA  3
8 NA  1 NA  3
9 NA NA  3  3
```

In each `gr` there is values in column `A`, `B and C`. My purpose is to find which column has the maximum value in that group and output that column name to new column called `col_name`.

if all values are equal to each other as in `gr=2` output is `all_equal`

if two of the column has max value comparing to the third column like in `gr=3` output column names `A&C` to the `col_name`.

I realized that it might be difficult to build a pipeline without `gather`

so I tried;

```
library(dplyr)
test%>%
  group_by(gr)%>%

  gather(variable, value, -gr) %>%
  arrange(gr)%>%
  mutate(col_name=variable[which.max(value)])

# A tibble: 18 x 4
# Groups:   gr [2]
   r    variable value col_name
   <fct> <chr>    <dbl> <chr>   
 1 1     A            5 A       
 2 1     A           NA A       
 3 1     A           NA A       
 4 1     B           NA A       
 5 1     B            2 A       
 6 1     B           NA A       
 7 1     C           NA A       
 8 1     C           NA A       
 9 1     C            1 A       
10 2     A            1 A       
11 2     A           NA A       
12 2     A           NA A       
13 2     B           NA A       
14 2     B            1 A       
15 2     B           NA A       
16 2     C           NA A       
17 2     C           NA A       
18 2     C            1 A
```

The problem I am struggling in here is how to output `all_equal` comment if all the max values are equal in columns A,B and C and

if 2 columns max value equals (A and C in gr=3) outputting those equal column names in this format `A&C` in `col_name`

The expected output would be

```
> test
       A  B  C gr  col_name
    1  5 NA NA  1     A
    2 NA  2 NA  1     A
    3 NA NA  1  1     A
    4  1 NA NA  2  all_equal
    5 NA  1 NA  2  all_equal 
    6 NA NA  1  2  all_equal
    7  3 NA NA  3  A&C
    8 NA  1 NA  3  A&C 
    9 NA NA  3  3  A&C
```

thx in advance!

Comment: Is your dataset always in this format, with 3 rows per group, and non-NA values only in the diagonal?

Comment: @Lamia yes most of the times with 3 rows per group and non-NA values diagonal.

Comment: @Lamia but I suppose generalized solutions are preferable for others that might have similar question in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a `dplyr` approach that I tried to make a little more generalized to accommodate a different number of columns of interest. With your `test` data frame from above, start by defining a function that finds the max of the current group, gets indices for columns with matching values, then builds the output based on the number of matching columns:

```
foo <- function(df_, cols = 1:3) {
  # Get max
  m = max(df_[, cols], na.rm = TRUE)

  # Get columns
  ix <- as.data.frame(which(df_[, cols] == m, arr.ind = TRUE))[, 2]
  matchlen = length(ix)
  columns <- names(df_[,cols])[ix]

  # Get varname based on length
  out = ifelse(matchlen == length(cols), "all_equal", paste(columns, collapse = "&"))
  df_$col_name = out
  return(df_)
}
```

Because the output from that is a data frame, you need to make use of `do` to apply it to groups with `dplyr`:

```
test %>%
  group_by(gr) %>%
  do(foo(.))

# A tibble: 9 x 5
# Groups:   gr [3]
      A     B     C gr    col_name 
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <fct> <chr>    
1     5    NA    NA 1     A        
2    NA     2    NA 1     A        
3    NA    NA     1 1     A        
4     1    NA    NA 2     all_equal
5    NA     1    NA 2     all_equal
6    NA    NA     1 2     all_equal
7     3    NA    NA 3     A&C      
8    NA     1    NA 3     A&C      
9    NA    NA     3 3     A&C
```

The function should allow for a flexible number of columns to be input, as long as they're numeric. For example,

```
test %>%
  group_by(gr) %>%
  do(foo(., cols = 1:2))
```

and

```
test %>%
  group_by(gr) %>%
  do(foo(., cols = c(1,3)))
```

both seem to work.

**Edit:**

Yeah, I guess you can!

```
test %>%
  group_by(gr) %>%
  do(foo(., cols = c("A", "B", "C")))
```

Comment: absolutely perfect. I knew the function would be complex! One more thing though can we explicitly say (A,B,C) instead of 1:3 in the foo function ?

Comment: @Alexander - It looks like it, have a look at the edit. If you want to reference it like `cols = c(A, B, C)`, I'm not sure that would work as-is, since R would think you're referencing an object in the environment.

Comment: Some strange thing is happened when I applied this function to my real data. The A,B,C columns are located 5,6 and 7 th column in my real data and column names in the real data like XX,YY and ZZ. Col name outputs first three column name even I put 5:7 in the foo function why this is happening ?

Comment: @Alexander - Whoops, sorry! I forgot to use the `[, cols]` for the naming section. Try the function now (edited).

Comment: yeap worked correctly! really appreciated it! Maybe will reach out if some unique thing happens in the real data;)

Comment: @Alexander, absolutely, feel free. I liked this problem!

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option using `gather`.  We `gather` the data into 'long' format, `arrange` by the group ('gr') and 'val' in descending order, grouped by 'gr', `summarise` to create the 'col_name' for each 'gr' based on the condition described in the OP's post and `right_join` with the original dataset

```
library(tidyverse)
test %>% 
   gather(key, val, -gr, na.rm = TRUE) %>%
   arrange(gr, desc(val)) %>%       
   group_by(gr) %>%         
   summarise(col_name = case_when(n_distinct(val)==1 ~ "all_equal",
                        TRUE ~ paste(key[val==max(val)], collapse = "&"))) %>% 
   right_join(test) %>%
   select(names(test), everything())
# A tibble: 9 x 5
#      A     B     C gr    col_name 
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <fct> <chr>    
#1     5    NA    NA 1     A        
#2    NA     2    NA 1     A        
#3    NA    NA     1 1     A        
#4     1    NA    NA 2     all_equal
#5    NA     1    NA 2     all_equal
#6    NA    NA     1 2     all_equal
#7     3    NA    NA 3     A&C      
#8    NA     1    NA 3     A&C      
#9    NA    NA     3 3     A&C
```

---

or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
library(stringr)
setDT(test)[, col_name := {
      v1 <- sort(na.omit(unlist(.SD)), decreasing = TRUE)
      if(uniqueN(v1)==1) "all_equal" else 
     paste(str_remove(names(v1)[v1==max(v1)], "\\d+"), collapse="&")
    }, by = gr]

test
#    A  B  C gr  col_name
#1:  5 NA NA  1         A
#2: NA  2 NA  1         A
#3: NA NA  1  1         A
#4:  1 NA NA  2 all_equal
#5: NA  1 NA  2 all_equal
#6: NA NA  1  2 all_equal
#7:  3 NA NA  3       A&C
#8: NA  1 NA  3       A&C
#9: NA NA  3  3       A&C
```

Comment: Thanks Akrun. Is possible to get same output without using `right_join` since its calling the original data frame. Like user defined function way as Luke J posted?

Comment: @Alexander If you don't want a join, then use `match`

Answer (score 2):

Similar to akrun's answer

```
library(tidyverse)

test <- data_frame(A=c(5,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,3,NA,NA),B=c(NA,2,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,1,NA),C=c(NA,NA,1,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,3),gr=gl(3,3))


test %>% gather(key, value, -gr, na.rm = TRUE) %>% 
  group_by(gr) %>% 
  arrange(gr) %>%
  mutate(col_name = if_else(length(which(value == max(value))) == length(unique(key)),
                     "all_equal",
                     paste(flatten(.[which(value == max(value)), "key"]), collapse = "&"))) %>% 
  spread(key, value)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#> # Groups:   gr [3]
#>   gr    col_name      A     B     C
#>   <fct> <chr>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 1     A             5     2     1
#> 2 2     all_equal     1     1     1
#> 3 3     A&C           3     1     3
```

Created on 2018-08-09 by the [reprex
package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

This will also condense the dataframe to remove all the extra `NA`s

Answer (score 1):

A solution using a custom function and data.table:

```
myfun <- function(x) {
    x <- as.matrix(x)
    idx <- apply(x, 2, max, na.rm=T)==max(x, na.rm=T)
    who <- colnames(x)[idx]
    if(length(who)==1) return(who)
    if(length(who)==2) return(paste0(who, collapse = "&"))
    if(length(who)>2)  return("all_equal")
}

library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(test)

dt[ , new := myfun(cbind(A,B,C)), by=gr]
```

Notice that I had to use `==max()` instead of `which.max` to deal with ties. I also struggled to implement this with a base function like `aggregate` so I went the `data.table` way.

Comment: perfect. Can we apply this myfun to `dplyr` ?

Comment: Probably.  I'm not yet a full tidyverse convert, so hopefully someone else can chime in.

Comment: Yeah I would appreciate if someone send some solution with `dplyr` :)

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 base `R` solutions

**Using `split<-` and `aggregate`**

```
test0         <- aggregate(test[1:3], by = test[4], max,na.rm=T)[-1]
nms           <- apply(do.call(pmax,test0) == test0, 1 , function(x) names(which(x)))
test$col_name <- NA
split(test$col_name, test$gr) <- 
  ifelse(lengths(nms) == 3, "all_equal", lapply(nms,paste,collapse="&"))
test
# A  B  C gr  col_name
# 1  5 NA NA  1         A
# 2 NA  2 NA  1         A
# 3 NA NA  1  1         A
# 4  1 NA NA  2 all_equal
# 5 NA  1 NA  2 all_equal
# 6 NA NA  1  2 all_equal
# 7  3 NA NA  3       A&C
# 8 NA  1 NA  3       A&C
# 9 NA NA  3  3       A&C
```

***details***

We first coalesce test into test0

```
test0
#   A B C
# 1 5 2 1
# 2 1 1 1
# 3 3 1 3
```

Then get the max rowwise with `pmax`, the column indices with `which` and the column names with  `names`.

We assign pasted names (with `"all_equal"` exception) with `split<-`, they're recycled to form the output.

**Using `stack` and `ave`**

```
stacked <- cbind(na.omit(stack(test,-gr)), gr=levels(test$gr))
test$col_name <-  with(stacked, ave(values, gr, FUN = function(x){
  nms <- paste(names(test)[which(x == max(x))],collapse="&")
  if (length(nms) == 3) "all_equal" else nms})[order(gr)])

#    A  B  C gr col_name
# 1  5 NA NA  1        A
# 2 NA  2 NA  1        A
# 3 NA NA  1  1        A
# 4  1 NA NA  2    A&B&C
# 5 NA  1 NA  2    A&B&C
# 6 NA NA  1  2    A&B&C
# 7  3 NA NA  3      A&C
# 8 NA  1 NA  3      A&C
# 9 NA NA  3  3      A&C
```